# MC can't Add a Cloud Storage Device

Tags: minio

I am trying to create a MinIO Server and Client so I can run some tests and I am getting the error bellow when I try to run mc:

```
C:\mc.exe alias set myminio http://169.254.44.236:9000 admin password

mc.exe: <ERROR> Unable to initialize new alias from the provided credentials. Get
"http://169.254.44.236:9000/probe-bucket-sign-6oubmdhiezos/?location=": dial tcp
169.254.44.236:9000: connectex: A socket operation was attempted on an unreachable network.
```

I just copied the command given to me when I started the MinIO Server. I am using a Windows10 PC remotely.

Comment: is this solved?

Comment: No, its not solved.